# WPF - Compilation error: Tags of type 'PropertyArrayStart' are not supported in template sections

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, compilation, dependency-properties

Ordinarily I wouldn't just post an error message on SO, but after a Google search only found one hit, I thought I'd at least open the floor for this error here on SO.

I have a custom control called `Sparkline` with a dependency property called `Values` of type `unit[]`.  Here's an example where I use it in a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Activity:ActivityHistory}">
    <Controls:Sparkline Grid.Column="1" Values="{Binding Path=Values}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

This code doesn't compile.  I receive the error message:

> *Tags of type 'PropertyArrayStart' are not supported in template sections.*

The line/column numbers indicate the start of the `Values` attribute.

This has really thrown me.  Searching on Google returned [one result](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/66c0d61d-1a04-4933-9227-98cb7fb4bb71) where [John_C](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/user?user=John_C) hit exactly the same issue.  Unfortunately, his solution involved moving the control to a separate assembly.  Well, mine's already in a separate assembly.  My guess is that something else is at play.

I've never heard of `PropertyArrayStart`.  Searching for that only return a few pages related to XAML serialisation.  Interesting stuff, but not much help.

Thinking about it, I can't think of any dependency properties in the framework that have array types.  Is this allowed?

I also tried using a nested element instead of a markup extension for the `Binding`.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Activity:ActivityHistory}">
    <Controls:Sparkline Grid.Column="1">
        <Controls:Sparkline.Values>
            <Binding Path="Values"/>
        </Controls:Sparkline.Values>
    </Controls:Sparkline>
</DataTemplate>
```

...still no luck.

Any ideas welcomed!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's been an eventful 27 minutes... :)

Changing the dependency property's type from `unit[]` to `IList<unit>` solved the problem.  Best of all, it didn't requite many code changes as the array already implements that interface.

I'm not sure whether dispatching to the array via the interface (callvirt) is slower.  My guess is yes.

The original error message hints that there's something going on here that I don't quite understand.  I'll accept any answer that explains it properly.

Comment: I also appreciate the response. Myself as well as everyone else were about to spend a bunch of time trying to figure this out.  One quick StackOverflow search was nice to find at midnight.  +1